# Swagger simple "in":"path" parameter not accepted

Tags: swagger

I have this segment in my swagger file

```
"/order/{order_id}":
            "delete": {
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "order_id",
                        "format": "int32",
                        "in": "path",
                        "type": "integer"
                    }
                ],
```

when i paste the entire file in the swagger editor:

[image]

Looks like the simplest param ever. I have no idea what's wrong with it. The error description doesn't help. Of course the specification file is enormous and complete, this is just a small section. If I change the `in:path` to e.g. `in:query`, it doesn't throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, didn't pay attention to this

[image]